# Converting Java Date to OffsetDateTime

Tags: java, spring, java-time, date

I have an eta value that is an OffsetDateTime and I have a scheduledDate that is a Date type. If the eta isn't set I want to fall back to the Date.

An example of the date is `Tue Jul 21 10:32:28 PDT 2020`. To convert this, I tried doing:

`OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(dto.getScheduledTime().ToInstant(), ZoneOffset.UTC)`

It feels like the utc offset is wrong since the Date has PDT in it already, but at the same time that's also not a timezoneId like "America/Los_Angeles".

I'm a little confused on how to handle this.

Comment: Date does *not* have PDT in it.  The string form of a Date is *displayed* in your system’s local timezone, but the Date object itself contains milliseconds since Jan. 1, 1970, nothing more.  That is why you must supply a timezone.  And UTC is probably the best choice, unless your application has a need to display it with a specific timezone.

Comment: Ahh okay. So the only reason why that PDT came up was because my systems timezone is from there? Am I on the right track by using the `.ofInstant` function and trying to convert the scheduledTime to an Instant?

Comment: Yes, I believe you are using the correct approach for converting a Date to an OffsetDateTime.

Comment: Okay so i'm not sure why, but today that line isn't returning null... Maybe I didn't save in the ide or something. But if you're saying the timezone in the string isn't going to be valid for other locations, I shouldn't be using ZoneOffset.UTC right?

Comment: In my opinion, you should use UTC.  Ignore the String form of Date objects;  it’s not actual data, just a convenient way of representing a Date.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime target, eta;    // Modern java.time class.
java.util.Date scheduledDate;  // Terrible legacy class.


if(Objects.isNull(eta)) {   // If no eta, fall back to scheduledDate.
    target = scheduledDate.toInstant().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ); // Never use legacy class `java.util.Date` -- when encountered, immediately convert to modern `java.time.Instant`. 
} else {  // Else not null.
    target = eta;
}
return target;
```

Better to completely avoid `java.util.Date`. When encountered, immediately convert to modern class `Instant`, and forget all about the `Date` object.

```
OffsetDateTime target, eta, scheduled;
scheduled = incomingJavaUtilDate.toInstant().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);

target = Objects.isNull(eta) ? scheduledDate : eta;  // Ternary operator. Short way of saying: If eta is null, go with scheduledDate, otherwise go with eta. 
return target;
```

## `Date::toString` lies to you

Firstly, understand that `java.util.Date` represents a moment in UTC, always in UTC<sup>†</sup>. However, its `toString` method has the well-intentioned by terribly confusing anti-feature of dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone. This creates the false impression that `Date` has a time zone when in fact it does not<sup>†</sup>.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

Secondly, you are needlessly and tragically mixing the very good modern *java.time* classes (`OffsetDateTime`) with the terribly awful legacy date-time classes (`Date`). Do not do this. Avoid the legacy classes entirely. They were obsoleted by the adoption of [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310) back in 2014.

[image: table of date-time classes in Java, both legacy and modern]

## Use *java.time*

If handed a `java.util.Date` object, immediately convert to *java.time*. Call the new conversion methods added to the old classes. The `Instant` class directly replaces `Date`, as a moment in UTC, but with finer resolution of nanoseconds versus milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();  // Convert from legacy class to modern class.
```

You should generally be tracking moments in UTC. You can do this as an `Instant` or as a `OffsetDateTime` with its offset set to `ZoneOffset.UTC` constant.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);  // Same moment, no change in meaning whatsoever.
```

For UTC specifically, there is no difference between the `instant` and the `odt` in our code here. They both represent a moment in UTC. The difference is that `OffsetDateTime` (a) could carry an alternate offset-from-UTC value (hours-minutes-seconds), and (b) is more flexible, such as generating text in formats other than standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Understand that an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) is merely a number of hours, minutes, and seconds. Nothing more. A [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone), in contrast, is *much* more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. For example, the people in region using `America/Los_Angeles` time zone change their offset-from-UTC twice a year in a silly practice known as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) going from -08:00 to -07:00 and back again.

So generally a time zone is preferable over a mere offset. For example, to see your `Date` we turned into a `Instant` through the wall-clock time used by most people on the west coast of US, apply the time zone `America/Los_Angeles` (`ZoneId`) to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(z);
```

You can get back to UTC by extracting a `Instant`.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

And from there get back to a `java.util.Date` (if you must, otherwise avoid).

```
java.util.Date d = java.util.Date.from(instant);
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Actually, the `java.time.Date` class *does* have a time zone buried deep inside. Lacking any accessor (get/set) methods, it is unreachable. Its behaviors do not relate to our discussion here. Confusing? Yes. Yet another of many reasons to avoid the terrible legacy date-time classes.